# Dynamically add child expander

Tags: wpf, dynamic, expander

Is there a way to create child expanders like this xaml bellow, at run-time?

```
<Expander Header="Building" IsExpanded="True">
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="Sales">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>6100</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>6101</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>6111</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>6150</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="Director">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>6102</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>6113</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Tags ***do not*** belong in the title, we have a tag section on this site, stop cluttering the title.

Answer (score 5):

Set a name for first StackPanel (MainStackPanel) under the top Expander.

```
// Add new expander, stack panel and text block.
var newExpander = new Expander {Name = "NewExpander", Header = "New Expander"};
var newstackPanel = new StackPanel {Name = "NewExpanderStackPanel"};
var newtextBlock = new TextBlock {Text = "777"};

// Add above items as children.     
newstackPanel.Children.Add(newtextBlock);
newExpander.Content = newstackPanel;
MainStackPanel.Children.Add(newExpander);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would probably be to use data binding. I'm assuming you have some data structure that describes which expanders you want to create. Let's assume we have:

```
class Building
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

class Item
{
    public int Number { get; }
}
```

In our user control, we'll set the `DataContext` to a list of `Building`s (e.g. in the constructor):

```
DataContext = GetListOfBuildings();
```

Then we'd use two nested `ItemsControl`s with templates to create the controls at runtime:

```
<Expander Header="Building"
          IsExpanded="True">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Number" />
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Expander>
```

This way you would not need to create controls in C#, which is more cumbersome in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about what you want to achieve.

If I understand correctly, you can save your code in a .xaml file as resource and use application to load it. Then, add the object to the visual tree.

```
  var expander = (Expander) Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("UriToTheXamlFile"));
  control.AddChild(expander);
```